# Hat disappears when I hover any profile

Tags: bug, winter-bash

When I hover a profile picture, the hat blinks and then disappears (stays in the back).

[image]

I've tested in many SE sites.

**OS:** macOS 10.13.2
**Browser:** Safari 11.0.2

I'm not using any browser extensions.

Comment: Work fine for me in Chrome and Firefox on Windows. Tested in meta.so, so, and SOpt

Comment: Reproduced with Safari on Mac

Comment: Works fine for me also. Firefox on Linux

Comment: Works fine for me too.  Chrome on Linux.